# Calendar event created using Microsoft Graph API. The webLink returned in the response is not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I created an event in a group calendar using [Microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

The weblink that is returned in the response after creating a calendar event, is not working. I want to open the calendar event in the read mode using this webLink.

The weblink, when pasted in the browser doesn't open the corresponding calendar event. It is just loading like this.

[image: Calendar event never loads]

Example webLink returned in the response:

webLink: "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=AAMkADE5YjI1MGNmLWFlZjUtNDVkOC04YTFkLWNkYjk4OWNiMTY4YwBGAAAAAAALwFEIZruUQLVjJFni3hGRBwAV%2BJi%2FVtMoTZmfylMD2ZC%2BAAAAAAENAAAV%2BJi%2FVtMoTZmfylMD2ZC%2BAAAZZtlRAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item"

I tried to make an url as suggested in [Graph Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/item/{event-id}](https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/item/%7Bevent-id%7D)

[https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid={event-id}&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item](https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=%7Bevent-id%7D&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item)

It doesn't work too.

Comment: If the URL doesn't open in browser then it sounds like there is an issue with the URL. Double check the documentation and [stitch the correct weburl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0). If you're using WebURL then you need to keep in mind that Outlook on the web opens the event in the browser if you are signed in to your mailbox. Not sure you tried that? If not, Outlook on the web prompts you to sign in. In case if you tried accessing the URL from an iFrame then it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dev. I created the URL in the same format as mentioned in Docs.
I am signed in with the correct user and I am not accessing this URL from an Iframe.

Comment: If its valid then the encoded url should open in IE/Edge/Chrome without any issue!!

Answer (score 0):

In OWA the issue occurs when the given calendar isn't previously opened. You can try opening the shared calendar in OWA by checking the box to open the group calendar and open the weblink again, it should do the trick.